# jQuery Validation plug-in, validating existing filled field

Tags: jquery-validate

just ran into this problem if i have a form field that is already filled and i press the submit button the validation does not take place but if i make a change to field (as in add a character or two0 then the validation takes place ......

```
<form id="form_state_edit" method="post" action="javascript:void(0);">
                <fieldset class="fieldset">
                <legend class="legend">Add a new State</legend>
                 <div id="form-wrapper-state-modal" style="width: 20rem;margin-left:5rem;margin-bottom:0.5rem;margin-top:-14px;"></div>
                <div style="">
                <p class="button-height inline-label">
                    <label class="label" for="state_name" style="display:inline;">State Name</label>
                    <input type="text" value="<?=$state_name?>" class="input  validate[required,custom[onlyLetterSp]]" id="state_name" name="state_name" style="width: 15rem;" />
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?=$state_arr[1]?>" id="state_id" name="state_id" />
                    <input type="hidden" value="edit" id="state_action" name="state_action" />

                    <button id="submit_state" class="button glossy mid-margin-right" type="submit">
                    <span class="button-icon">
                    <span class="icon-tick"></span>
                    </span>
                    Save
                    </button>
                    <div id="state_table_temp" style="display:none;"></div>
                </p></div>


                </fieldset>
            </form>

$("#form_state_edit").validationEngine('attach', {

          onSuccess: function(form, status){
            alert("The form status is: " +status+", it will never submit");
} ,
           onValidationComplete: function(form, status){
             alert("The form status is: " +status+", it will never submit");

           }
```

basically - if no change (as in i do not even click on the form field and do not enter anything) - onValidationComplete executes and status = true

if i do make a chnage - onSuccess executes...

what do i have to write so that even if the person has not made any changes (nor has clicked on the form field) to form field it wil do the validation and goto on success part ...

it seem that the ofr filed needs ot be "activated " before the validation can kick in.

\any idea ?

Comment: jQuery Validation Engine is not the same plugin as the hugely popular jQuery Validation by Jörn Zaefferer. I edited your question title to state you are using Engine

Comment: thanks and sorry i am using this one http://posabsolute.github.com/jQuery-Validation-Engine/

Comment: i know :) try my solution let me know what u got

Answer (score 0):

In the plugin's homepage, [here](http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/), you can see the following code

```
 alert( $("#formID1").validationEngine('validate') );
```

Try using that in the submit button's click event rather than an alert dialog, like so

```
$('#submit_state').click(function () {
   return $("#form_state_edit").validationEngine('validate');
});
```

Finally I would suggest wrapping your jQuery code in a document ready event handler. While not needed here. it is convention and saves you headaches if your code needs to reference DOM elements that are declared after it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //enter code here
});
```

---

Please bare in mind, I have not used this plugin before, but im pretty sure this should work

Comment: @dogku the code is wrapped correctly... and the above doesnt do anything....does not even throw an error message in the firebug...how ever i solved the issue (temp) by showing an alert asking the user to change the value if they want to save it

Comment: if you call $("#form_state_edit").validationEngine('validate') from the console in Firebug, does it validate correctly?

Comment: havent tried it ...but i gonna let this rest for the momement .as i have the workaround...thanks